# OpenLayers keep resetting after moving map

Tags: openlayers, wms, mapserver

I've an OpenLayers map in html that use WMS layers from a MapServer (in a docker) and the layer come from PostGIS.

When I'm on the map and drag the map, after two or three seconds the map goes back to the left

[image]

and the weirdest thing : Even if I zoom in, the scalebar change but my map still a the same scale

[image]

When I use the openlayers template for mapserver (something like http://127.0.0.1/?map=/etc/mapserver/mapfile.map&layer=rail&mode=browse&template=openlayers), I've no problem to drag and zoom in.

[image]

I've this problem with PostGIS layer and also spatialite layer (so I guess for all types of wms)

Any Ideas ? Codes below

**EDIT1** when I drag the scale is already changing, I think it's a projection problem but I can't find where

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            map
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.4.3/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.4.3/build/ol.js"></script>
            <style>
                .map{
                height: 400px;
                width: 50%;
                }
            </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>My Map</h2>
        <div id="map" class="map"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
            code: 'EPSG:31370',
            units: 'm'
        });

        var couche_wms= new ol.layer.Image({
                source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
                    url:'http://127.0.0.1/?map=/etc/mapserver/mapfile.map',
                    params:{

                        'LAYERS':'reg + rail',
                        'MODE':'map',
                        'TRANSPARENT' : 'true',
                        'FORMAT': 'image/png',
                        'tiled': 'true'
                    },
                serverType: 'mapserver',
                extent: [140000, 160000, 160000, 180000]
            })
        })

        var map = new ol.Map({
        renderer: 'webgl',
        controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([

            new ol.control.MousePosition({
            coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(0),
            className:'custom-mouse-position',
            undefinedHTML:'&nbsp;'
            }),

            new ol.control.ScaleLine()
            ]),
        layers :[couche_wms],
        target: 'map',

        view: new ol.View({
        projection: projection,
        zoom: 2,
        center: [150000,170000],

        })

        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my Mapfile

```py
MAP
    IMAGETYPE      PNG
    EXTENT         140000 160000 160000 180000
    SIZE           600 600
    DEBUG          ON
    PROJECTION
        "init=EPSG:31370"
        END

WEB
        METADATA
        "wms_title"     "WMS Server Demonstration"
        "wms_onlineresource" "http://127.0.0.1/?map=/etc/mapserver/mapfile.map"
        "wms_srs"       "EPSG:31370"
        "wms_enable_request" "*"
        END
END

LAYER
    NAME StreetSurface
    TYPE POLYGON
    CONNECTIONTYPE ogr
    CONNECTION "UrbAdmSpatialite.sqlite"
    DATA "select geometry from urb_a_ss"
    STATUS ON
    CLASS
        NAME "street_surfaces"
        STYLE
            COLOR 95 196 95
        END
    END
END

LAYER
    NAME reg
    TYPE LINE
    CONNECTIONTYPE POSTGIS
    CONNECTION "connectionstring"
    DATA "geom from region using unique id using srid=31370"
    STATUS ON

    CLASS
        NAME "Test"
        STYLE
            COLOR 0 0 0
        END
    END
END

LAYER
    NAME bu
    TYPE POLYGON
    CONNECTIONTYPE POSTGIS
    CONNECTION "connectionstring"
    DATA "geom from bu using unique id using srid=31370"
    STATUS ON

    CLASS
        NAME "Test"
        STYLE
            COLOR 0 0 0
        END
    END
END


LAYER
    NAME rail
    TYPE LINE
    CONNECTIONTYPE POSTGIS
    CONNECTION "connectionstring"
    DATA "geom from rail using unique id using srid=31370"
    STATUS ON

    CLASS
        NAME "Test"
        STYLE
            COLOR 194 118 222
        END
    END
END

END
```

Comment: To determine whether it's OpenLayers or MapServer, check the coordinates in the network requests.

Comment: Here is what I get from Network request but I don't understand : ```GET
 http://127.0.0.1/?map=/etc/mapserver/mapfile.map&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=reg&CRS=EPSG:31370&STYLES=&WIDTH=944&HEIGHT=400&BBOX=149668.125,169859.375,150331.875,170140.625```

Comment: Found my error thanks to the network requests ! Thank you @CL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error, I don't need the `mode=map` and `transparent=true` in the variable `couche_wms`".

It should look like this :

```js
        var couche_wms= new ol.layer.Image({
                source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
                    url:'http://127.0.0.1/?map=/etc/mapserver/mapfile.map',
                    params:{

                        'LAYERS':'reg + rail',
                        'FORMAT': 'image/png',
                    },
                serverType: 'mapserver',
            })
        })
```

And I also put the extent in `map` not in the variable `couche_wms`, so var map look like this:

```
        var map = new ol.Map({
        renderer: 'webgl',
        controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([

            new ol.control.MousePosition({
            coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(0),
            className:'custom-mouse-position',
            undefinedHTML:'&nbsp;'
            }),

            new ol.control.ScaleLine()
            ]),
        layers :[couche_wms],
        target: 'map',

        view: new ol.View({
        projection: projection,
        zoom: 2,
        center: [150000,170000],
        extent: [140000, 160000, 160000, 180000],

        })
```